# Get text in getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I am writing some javascript to be run in a bookmarklet that should get the text within a element that has a certain class name.

So for example

```
document.getElementsByClassName('price')
```

where the web page has or example

```
<span class="price">

    £23

</span>
```

How would I go about getting the actual text within the the element that has a class name price (i.e £23 in the above example).

Comment: If you have just one of them go ahead do.. `document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML` otherwise loop through the collection and get what you need.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements.  Traverse through that array and get the `innerText` property of each.  For example:

```
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++) {
  var price = priceEls[i].innerText;
  alert("Price: " + price);
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YQsBW/